# Can the "Enriched and Fortified" achievement in Gears of War 3 be obtained by staggering the waves?

Tags: achievements, gears-of-war-3

Can this achievement be obtained by staggering the waves? For example, if one night I complete waves 1-10 and the next day I start from wave 11 and complete up to wave 40, and the next day I complete waves 41-50, will I get the achievement?

Or will I have to complete it in a single play through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can get the achievement this way.

You can check your progress in the stats page from the main menu, although this will only show your progess in 10 wave chunks. For example, if you manage to complete wave 40, in the stats page you will see 'Wave 31 - 40' with a tick next to it. You can then complete wave 41 to 50 on another play through to get the achievement.

There is, however, a ribbon that you can get for completing wave 1 to 50 in one sitting (this is separate from the achievement, so you can view it as an additional challenge):

- *Long Hauler* – Completed all 50 waves in one session

Comment: Does not receiving the Long Hauler ribbon affect any of my other achievements?

Comment: No, the Long Hauler ribbon is not used for any achievements. It's only there for bragging rights if you do manage to get it.